# Python annotating points in a 3D scattter plot

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I want to give labels to each point (3D) in my data and the labels (the labels are keys in a dictionary) :

```
l = list(dictionary.keys())
#transform the array to a list
arrayx=arrayx.tolist()
arrayy=arrayy.tolist()
arrayz=arrayz.tolist()
#arrayx contains my x coordinates
ax.scatter(arrayx, arrayy, arrayz)
#give the labels to each point
for  label in enumerate(l):
    ax.annotate(label, ([arrayx[i] for i in range(27)],[arrayy[i]for i in range(27)],[arrayz[i] for i in range(27)]))
plt.title("Data")
plt.show()
```

My input :

arrayx:

```
[[0.7], [7.1], [7.5], [0.6], [0.5], [0.00016775708773695687]...]
```

arrayy:

```
[[0.1], [2], [3], [6], [5], [16775708773695687]...]
```

arrayz:

```
[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]...]
```

And give a label to each point 3D in the graph

Comment: please make a more clear minimal example with for example 3 points and their labels

Comment: Is there a reason why these are the lists/arrays are nested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

borrowing from @martin-evans's answer for the code, but using `zip`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

ax3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

arrayx = np.array([[0.7], [7.1], [7.5], [0.6], [0.5], [0.00016775708773695687]])
arrayy = np.array([[0.1], [2], [3], [6], [5], [16775708773695687]])
arrayz = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]])

labels = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

arrayx = arrayx.flatten()
arrayy = arrayy.flatten()
arrayz = arrayz.flatten()

ax3d.scatter(arrayx, arrayy, arrayz)

#give the labels to each point
for x_label, y_label, z_label, label in zip(arrayx, arrayy, arrayz, labels):
    ax3d.text(x_label, y_label, z_label, label)

plt.title("Data")
plt.show()
```

Comment: the (dis)advantage of this method is it will not throw an `IndexError` if `labels`, `arrayx`, `arrayy`, `arrayz` don't have the same length

Answer (score 5):

You could add text to each of your points as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

ax3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

arrayx = np.array([[0.7], [7.1], [7.5], [0.6], [0.5], [0.00016775708773695687]])
arrayy = np.array([[0.1], [2], [3], [6], [5], [16775708773695687]])
arrayz = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]])

labels = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

arrayx = arrayx.flatten()
arrayy = arrayy.flatten()
arrayz = arrayz.flatten()

ax3d.scatter(arrayx, arrayy, arrayz)

#give the labels to each point
for x, y, z, label in zip(arrayx, arrayy, arrayz, labels):
    ax3d.text(x, y, z, label)

plt.title("Data")
plt.show()
```

This would give you the following output:

[image: 3d scatter plot]